# 24 layers in unity3d for developing multiple mini games is not enough

Tags: unity-game-engine, layer, scene

My Team has a project to develop multiple mini games on different scenes in one project. I found that it will take 4 to 7 layers to work on one game, and the empty layer will soon be running out since we are developing many games.

We are thinking to write a script to manually control the collision by Physics.IgnoreCollision function. The question is that will this approach be efficient and necessary? Is there any proper way to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason the mini games can't re-use layers? Since they're in different scenes, there should be no issue...

Comment: And if they are separate games, just start separate projects. If you're worried about sharing code between project, then just figure out a decent method of versioning and check out your repository in each project.